# Combine Flow<List> and string in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Hey I am working in kotlin flow. I have flow in which I have list of data coming from server. And I want to filter text, I tried some piece of code but it's giving me problem. Can someone guide me on this. Thanks

**ExploreViewModel.kt**

```
class ExploreViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

    private val query = MutableStateFlow("")
    var queryText: String
        get() = query.value
        set(value) {
            query.value = value
        }
    val filteredTopics = MutableStateFlow<List<ConsultationTopics>>(emptyList())
    val filteredCategories = query
        .debounce(200) // low debounce because we are just filtering local data
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .combine(filteredTopics) { queryText, categoriesList ->
            val criteria = queryText.lowercase()
            if (criteria.isEmpty()) {
                    return@combine filteredTopics
            } else {
                categoriesList.filter { category -> category.title?.lowercase()?.let { criteria.contains(it) } == true }
            }
        }
}
```

I have `filteredTopics` property which have all data coming from server, `queryText` is using `onQueryTextChange` from `serarchview`. I am trying to filter the data and create new property called `filteredCategories` to pass this value to adapter. I am trying in `filteredCategories` I am checking `queryText` is empty then passing whole list otherwise pass filter list only, but I don't know this is correct way of doing or not.

**Error**

```
private fun setupFilteredTopic() {
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED) {
                viewModel.filteredCategories.collect { filteredTopicsList ->
                    consultationAdapter.submitList(filteredTopicsList)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Can someone guide me. Thanks

Comment: @HenryTwist How can we do that? Can you please guide me.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you returning elements of different types for filteredCategories

```
if (criteria.isEmpty()) {
    return@combine filteredTopics // type MutableStateFlow<List<ConsultationTopics>>
} else {
    categoriesList.filter { category -> category.title?.lowercase()?.let { criteria.contains(it) } == true } // type List<ConsultationTopics>
}
```

so you need to make a little change to your code, change `return@combine filteredTopics` by `return@combine filteredTopics.value`:

```
class ExploreViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

    private val query = MutableStateFlow("")
    var queryText: String
        get() = query.value
        set(value) {
            query.value = value
        }
    val filteredTopics = MutableStateFlow<List<ConsultationTopics>>(emptyList())
    val filteredCategories = query
        .debounce(200) // low debounce because we are just filtering local data
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .combine(filteredTopics) { queryText, categoriesList ->
            val criteria = queryText.lowercase()
            if (criteria.isEmpty()) {
                categoriesList
            } else {
                categoriesList.filter { category -> category.title?.lowercase()?.let { criteria.contains(it) } == true }
            }
        }
}
```

this should fix the error

Comment: you can use `categoriesList` from arguments instead of `return@combine filteredTopics.value` and `return@combine` is redundant

Comment: @IR42 can you please give me example. Thanks

Comment: you are right this will make the code cleaner, I edit the answer and add the edits suggested by @IR42

Comment: @MohamedRejeb One question is that is my filter code is correct? because when I filter and adding any text it return no data. Thanks

Comment: @ShreyaTiwari `category -> category.title?.lowercase()?.contains(criteria) == true` try this filter

Comment: @MohamedRejeb great thank you so much. One another question is what is `distinctUntilChanged()` function do ?

Comment: @ShreyaTiwari it will only emit new values to the flow if there is a change, so it will prevent emitting the same value multiple times, for example let's say that we have a `Flow<Int>`and when you collect it you receive these values (4, 4, 5, 4, 1, 1, 3), with `distinctUntilChanged()`you will only receive those values (4, 5, 4, 1, 3)

Comment: okk great answer. Thanks a milllion.

Answer (score 1):

You should return a list of `ConsultationTopics` objects in the `combine` block using `categoriesList` instead of `filteredTopics`:

```
val criteria = queryText.lowercase()
return@combine if (criteria.isEmpty()) {
     categoriesList
} else {
     categoriesList.filter { category -> category.title?.lowercase()?.let { criteria.contains(it) } == true }
}
```

Or we can omit the `return@combine` operator:

```
val criteria = queryText.lowercase()
if (criteria.isEmpty()) {
     categoriesList
} else {
     categoriesList.filter { category -> category.title?.lowercase()?.let { criteria.contains(it) } == true }
}
```

Comment: Why just not  replace `filteredTopics.value` with `categoriesList`? It would be nicer and cleaner.